# Website looks good in all browsers and versions except IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have energyshop.se which looks good in Chrome, IE8-9, Firefox but not in IE7 as one of my friends noticed. There both menu and footer are not longer horizontal but vertical.

How do I solve this?

Here are CSS for my topmenu in the header and footermenu:

```
#main_menu {
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:24px;
background-color:#1ca46e;
height:45px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
width:850px;
margin-left:22px;
margin-bottom: -35px;
margin-top: -30px;
top:100px;
}

#main_menu a {
    color:#ffffff;
    height: 10px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 105px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background-color:#1ca46e;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-color: white;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:28px;
}

#main_menu a:hover {
    color:#555;
}

#main_menu li.current-menu-item a {
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #403F40;
    }

#footer_menu {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    height:75px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    margin-top:25px;
    margin-left:50px;
    color:#9221a6;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
#footer_menu a {
    margin:5px; 
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    color: #9221a6;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Paste your CSS code for the menu, please.

Comment: I can add that after downlaoding a IE-lookup software both IE6 and IE5 looks bad too. I paste the CSS now, hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "display: inline;" to your footer.. It should help you. Tell me if it doesn't I'll try to figure out something else ;)

Comment: I tried this with no result. The problem is that even though float is on the elements wont float in a horizontal line, just as a vertical group.

Comment: Is there something that's restricting your element's width? This is just a guess, I'm on my way from work at the moment so I can't check stuff like that by myself right now..

Comment: It doesnt seem to be that, because other <a> element wont float either. Its like in this version of IE nothing wants to float and the display:inline doesnt change anything.

Comment: But I mean try setting the width of the container to a high enough value.. the parent to the elements that you don't want to display vertically.. doesn't work?

Comment: Actually im stupid. I didnt use the display:inline on the correct place, now I added it to both menus (menu li {display:inline}) and i got them both to line up! Many thanks bro

Comment: One question tho, there are smalla differences in the "perfect" Chrome and these IE6/IE7 but not many. I tried to use css conditional if the user used IE6/IE7 use some margins and so-on but did not get it too work. Is it worth the time to get it done, are there enough people out there using IE6/IE7?

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of people are still using IE6/7.. Depends on what users you're targeting. But I know how you feel, I hate customizing my code for old browsers too ;) At least you got it to work correctly.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the css property `list-style-type:none;` that in IE7 (but not in 8), only removes the bullets on the `<li>` elements...

try to add the css property `display:inline;` to solve it...

Comment: I dont use any list-style property for either menus, should I set that to none, or keep it like I have it?

Comment: leave at it is but probably you have to made more changes, so maybe it's worthy the effort of create a css for fixing this little annoyances and wrap it with a conditional comment ([link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment), because probably there will be more problems...

Comment: Thank you, thats what I did. And I can really recommend doing a second CSS (for older IE) which you call in your header: <!--[if lt IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ielt8.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
<![endif]--> This will also let you edit the orginal css for "all" browsers and not worry about messing up ur IE settings.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`  on your website, I am assuming that you are using some of the `html5` only features.
That may be the reason why `IE7` not rendering properly.
One way to solve this problem is use

http://www.modernizr.com/

Good luck